# all functionals in a Banach space acting on an element give zero

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $X^*$ denote the dual space. Suppose that $u \in X$ is such that $\langle f,u \rangle_{X^* \times X} = 0$ for all $f \in X^*$. Is it necessarily the case that $\|u\|_{X} = 0$?

It is clear that this is the case whenever $X$ is Hilbert space because we can define a functional $f_u$ by $f_u(v) = \langle v,u\rangle$ for all $v \in X$, and then by setting $v = u$ we conclude that $\|u\|_{X}^2 = 0$. So, my question is really about Banach spaces that do not have an inner product structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $\|u\|_{X}=\sup\{|\left<f,u\right>|: f\in B_{X^{\ast}}\}$ by Hahn-Banach Extension Theorem, so $\|u\|_{X}=0$ in this case.